# How to write ajax with php in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, wordpress

When the user clicks my submit button, I want to send a POST request to a special URL that was created based on information in the form. I also want it to insert a row to the WordPress MYSQL database.

I appended to end of `admin-ajax.php`:

```
function add_query_db_callback(){

global $wpdb;

    $id_instagram = $_POST['id_instagram'];
    $table_name = 'wp_insta_email';

        $data_array = array(
            'id_instagram' => $id_instagram
        );

        $rowResult = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data_array, $format=NULL);

echo $_POST['data'];

if (!$rowResult) {
    echo "FAILED TO UPDATE";
} else {
    $rowResult;
    echo "WILL UPDATE SUCCESSFULLY - CALL RESULT FUNCTION";
};

wp_die();
die();
    
}`
```

and in file `header.php`:

```
    <!-- Search_box --> 
<div class="s006">
    <form  method="post" id="form_id" onsubmit="return myFunction()">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="inner-form">
                <div class="input-field">
                    <button class="btn-search" type="button submit" value="Submit" name="BtnSubmit">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
                            <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                    <input id="search" type="text" placeholder=" INPUT YOUR ID INSTAGRAM " value="" name="id_instagram"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    var act= "//example.com/public/"+document.getElementById("search").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("search").value;
    document.getElementById("form_id").action = act;
    document.getElementById("form_id").submit();
    if (name == '') {
        alert("Please Fill All Fields");
    } else {
        // AJAX code to submit form.
        var ajaxData = {
            'action': 'add_query_db',
            'id_instagram': name
        }
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
            data: ajaxData,
            success: function( response ) {
                console.log("Data returned: " + response );
                $statusSelectCell.parent().css({"background-color": "#b3e6b3"});
                $statusSelectCell.parent().animate({backgroundColor: currentBackgroundColor}, 1200);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("FAILED TO POST DATA!!");
            }

    });
    }
    return act;
}
</script>
```

but it doesn't save to my database (only pass to my intended URL).

Comment: Did you check if the request is reaching the POST URL? I'd suggest using a separate JavaScript file included with [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) along with [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) to include the Ajax URL via variables.

Comment: as a note, you shouldn't mix PHP and JS - they're executed differently and can lead to unexpected behaviour,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you invoke `document.getElementById("form_id").submit()` function in your javascript code?

Actually `.submit()` function redirects you to the intended url and the lines below it are not executed.

Or if you want to redirect to the specific page then you need add the code in the very bottom of the ajax `success` section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    var act= "//example.com/public/"+document.getElementById("search").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("search").value;
    document.getElementById("form_id").action = act;
    // document.getElementById("form_id").submit();
    if (name == '') {
        alert("Please Fill All Fields");
    } else {
        // AJAX code to submit form.
        var ajaxData = {
            'action': 'add_query_db',
            'id_instagram': name
        }
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
            data: ajaxData,
            success: function( response ) {
                console.log("Data returned: " + response );
                $statusSelectCell.parent().css({"background-color": "#b3e6b3"});
                $statusSelectCell.parent().animate({backgroundColor: currentBackgroundColor}, 1200);

                // if you want to be redirected place submit function here
                document.getElementById("form_id").submit();
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("FAILED TO POST DATA!!");
            }

    });
    }
    return act;
}
</script>
```

hope this will help you

Comment: Did you try the code I wrote above? If you don't want to redirect then you can remove the document.getElementById() function on success section.

Comment: I delete  the code  `document.getElementById("form_id").submit();` 
, but it did not work

but i want to redirect a specific url